# DbContext behave differently within different classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, azure

I have a local *ASP.NET MVC 3 Windows Azure Project* where I use a local instance of *MSSQL Express* for my emulator.

In my **web.config** I have the following connection string:

`<add name="ExampleDb" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ExampleDb;User Instance=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

For debugging purposes I have the following in my **WebRole.cs** file:

```
public override bool OnStart() 
{
    ExampleDb context = new ExampleDb();
    context.ExampleItemEntries.Add(new ExampleItem() { ExampleItemId = 1, Att1 = "1", Att2 = "2" });
    context.SaveChanges();     
    return base.OnStart();
}
```

When I perform this action I can actually see the content in my code-first generated database (using Entity Framework). Database: ExampleDb, Table: ExampleItem.

However, doing the exact same thing in *ExampleController* **does NOT** update the database. Instead this data goes somewhere else (I have no idea where). When I visit my controller via the browser I can upload data and look at it but it is not stored in my ExampleDb database, only data sent from WebRole.cs is in the database.

*Any ideas what's causing this behaviour?*

**ExampleDb.cs** looks like this:

```
public class ExampleDb : DbContext
{
    public ExampleDb() : base("ExampleDb") { }
    public DbSet<ExampleItem> ExampleItemEntries { get; set; }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string contains 'User Instance=True'. This means that SQLEXPRESS uses a user instance to store your data. This is a completely different instance of SQL Server that contains a new set of databases.

I assume the code in WebRole.cs is run in a different user account than the code in ExampleController. When the ExampleController is run under a user account that is not an administrator, a user instance is used...

So when you remove 'User Instance=True' from your connectionstring and assign the proper access rights to your SQLEXPRESS database instance, that would solve the problem.

Comment: You were correct. Thanks for taking time investigating the matter.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeFirst Model you should define the connection string in the web.config first as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ExampleDbConnection"
      connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
                   database=ExampleDb;
                   AttachDBFilename=|YouDataDirectory|yourdb.mdf;
                   User Instance=true"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<connectionStrings/>
```

The DbContext class constructor accepts a name-value pair specifiying connection-string name in web.config. So you can reference this connection string in your context:

```
class ExampleDb : DbContext
{
  public ExampleDb() : base("name=ExampleDbConnection") { }
  ...
}
```

This code does work fine in a ASP.NET MVC Web Role so you can try as above.